# Remove a single instance of a String stored in a ParseObject Array List

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to remove a single instance of a string from an Array field in Parse:

```
final ParseObject post = mPosts.get(position);
List<String> repliedToByList = post.getList("repliedToBy"); // Retrieve current list
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
repliedToByList.remove(currentUserObjectId); // Remove first instance of specified objectid
post.remove("repliedToBy"); // Clear the entire list
post.addAllUnique("repliedToBy", Collections.singletonList(repliedToByList)); // Add the new list
```

That string is the current user's objectId, which is added when a user replies to a "post", as such:

```
post.addAll("repliedToBy", Collections.singletonList(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()));
```

For example, the Array contains:

```
["1RtqEgy1ct","f4qEWY8UOM","f4qEWY8UOM"]
```

Is there any way to just remove one single instance of `f4qEWY8UOM`? The alternative is to do everything using increments/decrements, but that is not ideal for me.

Comment: convert the list to an instance of ArrayList and iterate over its entries instead of calling List.remove()

Comment: On the server, I've stored the array as a variable, then iterated through looking for my string, and if I found it removed that index's value from the array + break out of the loop, then store the variable as the object's value for the right key, rather than using their add / remove methods.

Downside is that this likely causes the database to reindex the array, which could take a while depending on how many indexes you have using this key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing my replyCount is easy:

```
// Increment replyCount
postObject.increment("replyCount", 1);
postObject.saveInBackground();
```

But there is something wrong with the Android Parse SDK's stated decrement method, i.e. `postObject.increment("replyCount", -1)`, so I tried the following:

Instead of storing a list of objectIds in a list and then counting its size, I simply increment/decrement in the following way, by always fetching the previous replyCount, subtracting 1, and then saving the new put call:

```
// Decrement replyCount
int newReplyCount = postObject.getInt("replyCount") - 1;
postObject.put("replyCount", newReplyCount);
postObject.saveInBackground();
```